# Close an option position after getting an early assignment notice

Tags: options, assignment

If  I sell an option, and the option goes in the money prior to expiration, and I get hit with an early assignment notice, can I still close out the option after I get early assignment notice?

I was of the impression that we can close out an option any time prior to expiration, not sure how it works with early assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sold a call, I trust? I bought a call. I have the right to exercise at my will. No sense if out of the money, of course, but if in the money, I might want to capture a dividend or just start the clock for long term gains. Once I exercise, you have no option (pun intended) but to let it go. 
The assignment is notification, not a request for permission.